# Inquiry on Node.js HTTP requests/responses and URL as primary key for this JSON-formatted document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database, nosql

I have a script that uses Node.js to request headers from a specific site.

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

var hostNames = ['www.google.com'];

var options = {
            host: hostNames[i],
            path: '/'
    };

http.get(options, function(res) {

        var obj = {};
        obj.statusCode = res.statusCode;
        obj.headers = res.headers;

        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));
    })
```

The output, for the URL "www.google.com" would be attached below:

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "date": "Mon, 04 Mar 2013 16:43:39 GMT",
        "expires": "-1",
        "cache-control": "private, max-age=0",
        "content-type": "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",
        "set-cookie": [
            "PREF=ID=cfa31a2cae817ca6:FF=0:TM=1362415419:LM=1362415419:S=m-sNTevwPhFFWVpv; expires=Wed, 04-Mar-2015 16:43:39 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com",
            "NID=67=AKMqJ9Q94GtcmF0kTOAOLgFLqz9XAnSwVe4jzzXFVhvxuxRJP_l9QEwbjR3F7d506thF9BURyGJUz5DuNTEzXesit50Dm7FlOoVuL2qGRt9XZwRMGjAlxL5heO4vIATp; expires=Tue, 03-Sep-2013 16:43:39 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly"
        ],
        "p3p": "CP=\"This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info.\"",
        "server": "gws",
        "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
        "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
        "transfer-encoding": "chunked"
    }
}
```

My question is in-regards to JSON. I am trying to store the output into MongoDB. MongoDB stores JSON-like documents. From my understanding, SQL-based databases have a primary key. This is where my confusion comes in. I would like to use the URL, in this case, 'www.google.com' as the primary key. How do I achieve this? This is my first time using JSON-like storing structures, and the multiple articles I have read do not really apply to my specific situation.

When I search for "www.google.com" in the database, the plan is to have the headers show up, under "www.google.com." I don't know - I think I am still thinking in the SQL mindset. Can someone share some insight to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [official docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/object-id/) on object ids.

So you can create your own object id for a record using anything with appropriate format (hex number) and length, so this will work

```
db.names.insert({"_id": new ObjectId("012345678901234567890123"), "name" : "my name" })
```

but this dont

```
db.names.insert({"_id": new ObjectId("my reallllly long string"), "name" : "my name" })
```

you will need to use hash of your url if you want to using at object id.

However mongo gives you another option. leave _id field alone and create url field for url, and than set index on url field

```
db.scrapedPages.ensureIndex({ 'url': 1})
```

UPDATE: more specifically to your example.
You are not going to set/change `_id` property, mongo does it for you.
Instead you are going set `url` property of document to save, and reasonable thing to use here is your options object, as it defines the page you are parsing.

So I think you'll endup with something like that ( I expect you use mongo native driver and have mongo connection open )

```
var options = {
        host: hostNames[i],
        path: '/'
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
    var obj = {
       url: options.host + options.path // or whatever else is 
       statusCode : res.statusCode,
       headers : res.headers
    }
    save(obj, function(err, objects) {
       if (err) console.warn(err.message);
    })
})

function save(doc, callback) {
    var collection = new mongodb.Collection(client, 'test_collection')
     , cb = callback || function() {}
    collection.insert(doc, {safe:true}, cb);
}
```

Comment: Hi vittore. In my case for my output code - could you demonstrate to me the format in which, with my example, how I would incorporate either the `_id` and/or `'url'` into it? Thank you.

Comment: Specifically, does the `url` field encompass the entire response header {} or does it occupy the same line as `statusCode`?

Comment: Gotcha. How does this look `
db.users.ensureIndex({url:1},{unique:true});`

Comment: you can run it by hand just connecting to mongo console exactly with this command, alternatively check docs section on indexes https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/docs/indexes.md

Answer (score 0):

The `primary key` in an SQL table is a column that is used to uniquely identify a particular row. In mongodb `_id` is the field which is the primary key. `mongodb` adds it automatically if you don't specify it and assigns an `ObjectId` (12 byte long BSON identifier) to it. You can check the details [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/object-id/).